# How to access the elements of an iframe from another domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

EDIT: I take the src of the iframe using getFrame then i try and get the src of a video in another function called getSrc. For some reason i'm still getting undefined returns. Here's a picture of the console as a result of the logs in getSrc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1bNy.png

```
getFrame = function(links) {
   return $q.all(links.map(function(link){
      return $http.get(link.Address);
  })).then(function(results){
      var src = results.map(function(result){
        var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
        tmp.body.innerHTML = result.data;
        var video = $(tmp.body.children).find('#definitionblock iframe');
        var video_src = $(video[0]).attr("src");
        return "http://bslsignbank.ucl.ac.uk" + video_src;
      });
      return src;
  })
}

getSrc = function(links) {
  return $q.all(links.map(function(link){
     return $http.get(link);
 })).then(function(results){
     var src = results.map(function(result){
       var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
       tmp.body.innerHTML = result.data;
       //console.log(tmp);
       var video = $(tmp.body.children).find('#sign');
       console.log(video[0]);
       var video_src = $(video[0]).attr("poster");
       //console.log(video_src);
       return video_src;
     });
     return src;
 })
}
```

This is where the functions are called:

```
bslLogin.getFrame($scope.links).then(function(response) {
        $scope.videos = response;
        bslLogin.getSrc($scope.videos).then(function(response) {
          $scope.srcs = response;
        });
});
```

If I don't specify a video index when i'm logging video[0], i get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/utXnj.png

Something is being found but I don't know how to get it in the right form to get the video src.

Comment: Simple answer is you cannot access cross domain iframe content using javascript if not explecitely allowed by server. You could proxify it on your own server or use a browser extension

Comment: I'm using this code as part of hybrid mobile app made in Ionic. So i don't know if I have that option.

Comment: I'm not a ionic developer but i'd say something should be possible. If you request the website content from your ionic app, you shouldn't have to worry about same origin policy. So you could get this website content source from this request.I'm wondering in your code what gives you `console.log(result.data);`? Cannot you get video src from here, without embeding it in a iframe? Or if like your code could suggest it, the requested website contains a iframe which contains the video, is it? If ya, then get this iframe source and makes a new http request to get the video src attribute

Comment: I can't get the video src from that link, no. But I could make a new http request to the iframe source and see if that works. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @A.Wolff I've made some changes to the program and updated my initial post with an edit. For some reason i'm getting similar issues. If it's a permission problem then why aren't I getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities:

1. if you can control the server side you need to enable CORS on your server
2. if you can control the iframe content page you may use the postMessage

Refer to: [Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: I'm webscraping off a client's website and I don't think they'd be willing to change these things on their side.

Comment: @Inalek I understood you are experiencing problems on a task. But according to my experience this is the answer. A Client offered me a lot of money: no one got the job and solved. If one guy will answer you I'm happy to learn.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. Hopefully somebody else will answer as well.